# Permission denied error with XAMPP

Tags: permissions, xampp

Complete noob with ubuntu and linux here, so excuse the "noobity". I'm using Ubuntu desktop 16.04 LTS.

Installed XAMPP yesterday, viewed my site on it and all was good. After a restart, while trying to do some of the things I did yesterday -simple functions like editing files or copy and paste- I'm getting a "Error opening file 'filename': Permission denied" error.

EDIT: I'm also seeing lockpads on the opt/lampp directory's contents.

I searched before sending this question, but found nothing that I understood. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: "Installed XAMPP yesterday" first mistake and all your other mistakes can be avoided due to that one  ;-)  We have a native "almost one click to get it working" installation of a LAMP (Linux Apache Mysql Php/python/perl) with `sudo apt install lamp-server^` (mind the carrot) that will have you end up with a http://localhost showing "It Works".

Comment: But ... " -simple functions like editing files or copy and paste- I'm getting a "Error opening file 'filename': Permission denied" error." does not look like it should be related to your xampp installation??

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind. You noticed the "Complete Noob" part, right? ;) I installed using bitnami. Guess that's what you're talking about? Yes. It's possible it's an Ubuntu permissions thing. Only happened after the installation of Xampp AND only in the lampp directory

Comment: Yeah saw that ;-)  Can you copy the commands and errors you get into the question and also the results of `ls -l` (to limit the result you probably only need that for that file you get the errors from)

Comment: I'm also seeing lockpads on the opt/lampp directory's contents. Results are 10000+ files for the root directory. ./opt/lampp# ls -l
total 10416

Answer (score 1):

First

```
cd /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin
```

Give permission to config.inc.php

```
sudo chmod -R 777 config.inc.php
```

Edit config.inc.php file

```
gedit config.inc.php
```

Go to line or search for `// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';`

Remove `//` from `//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';`

Edit it with from Localhost to 127.0.0.1

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

Now restart services

```
service mysql restart
```